# How to Add Table Filter with JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I've been trying to add a search filter to a table using JavaScript, I've downloaded jQuery on my computer as well as for browser but the search filter still won't work.

```js
var $rows = $('#table tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, '' ).toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="top">
  <!--id "top" for a "return to top of page" button-->
  <h1>
    <!--header-->
    CryptoCost<img width="25">
    <font size="4"><span class="Priceandmarketcap">Live Cryptocurrency Prices & Market Capitalization</span></font>
    <font size="2"><span class="SearchCoinsHead">Search Coins: 
            <font><input type="text" id="search" class="light-table-filter" placeholder="BTC.."></font></span></font>
  </h1>
</header>
<br>
<!--vertical whitespace-->

<span class="indextable">
        <table id="table">
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>    <!--table headers-->
            <th>Coins</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>24H Change</th>
            <th>24H Volume</th>
            <th>Market Cap</th>
            <th>Circulating Coin Supply</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>    <!--start of new row-->
            <td>1</td>    <!--coin number-->
            <td><a href="BTCprice.html"> <img src="" width="15"> BTC </a></td>    
            <!--icon & ticker-->
            <td><big>$7000</big></td>    <!--price-->
            <td><big>-15%</big></td>    <!--24H % Change-->
            <td><big>30,284 BTC</big></td>    <!--24H Volume-->
            <td><big>$117,727,059,656</big></td>    <!--Market Cap-->
            <td><big>16,946,875 BTC</big></td>    <!--Circulating Coin Supply-->
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td><a href="ETHprice.html"> ETH </a></td>
            <td><big>$400</big></td>
            <td><big>+32%</big></td>
            <td><big>98,497,625 ETH</big></td>
            <td><big>$37,143,553,062</big></td>
            <td><big>98,497,625 ETH</big></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td><a href="LTCprice.html"> <img src="" width="15"> LTC </a></td>
            <td><big>$120</big></td>
            <td><big>-40%</big></td>
            <td><big>55,849,820 LTC</big></td>
            <td><big>$6,269,309,798</big></td>
            <td><big>55,849,820 LTC</big></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </span>
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those situations where you really should just go ahead and choose a library. Reason being is you are most likely going to want to add additional features (like your filtering) and "reinventing the wheel" isn't the best approach in many cases.

I would *highly* suggest a free and open-source library called, DataTables. It will provide an incredible amount of features (including filtering) and will also provide you with a fully responsive table implementation - which is critical nowadays. In addition, it is based off of jQuery - which you are already using:

https://datatables.net/

If you are just playing around then please ignore this answer - but if you're creating a real website that will be published I'd suggest using a library.

Comment: thanks! god datatables and it works like a charm. Now just need to figure out how to edit the tables...

Answer (score 0):

You're not including your script correctly.
This:

```
<script>
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery- 
3.3.1.min.js"integrity="sha256- 
FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Should be:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8" crossorigin="anonymous">
```